# Why were these load bearing walls not stacked?

Tags: framing, structural

I was making a model of a house to help design a renovation and in my measuring I discovered that the center load bearing wall on the first floor was not centered over the load bearing beam and columns in the basement below by a difference of about 8". The cross section shown below is to scale and is the entire house; it's a 20' x 40' rectangle in plan. First floor joists are 2x8's and ceiling joists are 2x6's. Upper space is finished and is an occupied bedroom. It’s in the state of Wisconsin, USA. House was built in 1930, every framing member is douglas fir.

I found this to be so strange. Is there any reason to do this other than lending asymmetry to the floor plan? Is this legit? This seems like an unstable arrangement in the long term.[image]

Comment: Where is the house? So we know what building code applies.

Comment: It’s in Wisconsin, USA

Comment: I wonder if, when the house was built, it was not intended for the attic space to be finished. If the attic were empty then that first floor bearing wall would be carrying only the weight of the first floor ceiling.

Comment: Do you see any signs of instability (e.g. cracks, bowing of posts, sagging joists, etc.)? I would think that if it was an *"unstable arrangement in the long term"* then you would see some signs, being that it has stood now for **nearly 90 years**; to me, that qualifies as "long term".

Comment: Greg - there is a staircase leading to the upstairs space original to the house, so I think it was always intended to be occupied.

Comment: Jimmy - there is a slight hump down the middle of the house atop the beams in the basement, and the posts supporting said beams are not plumb anymore, if they ever were. The whole house does have a very slight list to it.

Comment: IIRC, rule of thumb is Code allows offset up to the width of the beam, [provided it is not an I-joist](https://www.techsupport.weyerhaeuser.com/hc/en-us/articles/205285780-Offset-Bearing-Walls). Lumber yards often have engineers on staff who can advise if further calc are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why it was done?  Because the designer wanted the wall in one place upstairs and another place downstairs.

Is this legit?  I can't answer whether it was to code when first built, or whether it is still to code, but I am pretty sure it is safe.  Essentially the first floor wall is being supported by a cantilevered beam projecting out from the ground floor wall.  Given that the beam is 8" deep, cantilevering out by 8" wouldn't concern me at all.

Given that the structure has stood for 89 years thus far, it is probably good for another 89 years. Don't worry about it.

Having said that, you *do* need to make sure that your remodelling allows for the extra stresses this creates.  So beware if you need to cut holes in the timbers for pipework or electrical; you need holes rather than notches even more than usual.

Comment: +1 for reminding OP about future remodeling considerations.

Comment: @LeeSam Yup "It's stood this long, it'll stand longer" doesn't apply if you make changes.